# CakePHP RESTful API routing with custom querystring params

Tags: rest, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.x for a RESTful API, I want to be able to handle requests in the following form

```
api/activity/17?page=1&limit=10
```

Typically CakePHP I think likes each param to be separated by the forward slash char and then each of these is mapped into the variables defined in the 2nd array argument of router::connect above. For exampple:

```
api/activity/17/1/10
```

In my case though this won't work so I am trying to pass a custom query string which I will then decode in my controller. My router connect is as follows:

So I am using router::connect as follow:

```
Router::connect('/api/activity/:queryString', [
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'activity',
    '[method]' => 'GET',
    'ext' => 'json',
],
[
    'queryString' => '[0-9]+[\?]...[not complete]'
]);
```

I can't get the regular expression to accept the '?' which I am exscaping in the regex above. How can I achieve this or otherwise is there a better or easier way of sending the URL in the format I require.

Comment: The router doesn't support matching query strings... but why do you need to match on them at all? Why would you not connect to the controller/action if say `limit` wasn't passed? Wouldn't it make more sense to simply use default values in that case?

Comment: Why must you use a query string? A well-designed REST API normally has a structure like this anyway: `api/activity/17/page/1/limit/10` Does that work for you?

Comment: @BadHorsie `A well-designed REST API normally has a structure like this anyway` I've never seen/written/used an api implementing pagination like that

Comment: I agree this specific case not with pagination (I was just giving OP a suggestion with his existing parameters, I didn't really think about that he was going pagination), but the pattern itself is pretty common if you use any large well-known API (e.g. MailChimp) where you are accessing more than one related member with one request. http://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/

Comment: What is the problem with just processing the query string in the controller from `$this->request->query` if it's for pagination? Why the need to try to connect it through a route?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL parameters (among other methods) via `$this->request->query;`

So, in your example, add the following in method `view()` of `app/Model/Activity.php`:

```
<?php

// file app/Model/Activity.php

public function view($id)
{
  // URL is /activity/17?page=1&limit=10
  echo $this->request->query['page'];  // echo's: 1
  echo $this->request->query['limit'];  // echo's: 10
}
```

See ['Accessing Querystring parameters'](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-querystring-parameters) in the CakePHP book